# Authenticating users via Google APIs OAuth2 to use Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm currently trying to make a google chrome extension that will 'like' or 'favorite' a youtube video if you upvote it on Reddit. Obviously, you need the user to be logged in and authenticate said user so you can like or favorite the video.

My question is how exactly do I go about doing this? I've tried doing some research but I'm still completely lost on where the user authentication comes in or how the user signs in if not already. I'm assuming I need to use OAuth2 in order to like the video on youtube, but how do I implement that in my extension?

So far, all I have are my content.js and manifest.json:

```
    {
      "name": "VideoUpLike",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Likes the video on YouTube after upvoting a YouTube link on Reddit",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "permissions": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
      ],
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://www.reddit.com/*", "https://www.reddit.com/*"],
          "js" : [ "contentscript.js"]
        }],
      "background": {
        "page": ["Auth.html"]
      }
    }
```

and my text content.js script to test the upvote button click:

```
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.matches('.arrow.upmod')) {
            alert("Oh hi there");
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome Identity API to authenticate users for a chrome extension. The steps are:

1. Add permissions to your manifest and upload your app.
2. Copy key in the installed manifest.json to your source manifest, so that 3. your application ID will stay constant during development.
3. Get an OAuth2 client ID for your Chrome App.
4. Update your manifest to include the client ID and scopes.
5. Get the authentication token.

(From https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity)

I found this video really useful to see how to implement this in your code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeUMKlCTdHg

Finally, Google also have some example projects on github which might be worth looking at - I am unable to post more links, but you can find them by searching.

Comment: The youtube link is dead, and step #2 is incredibly obtuse.